# Jquery UI Dialog position onmouseover without using selector

Tags: jquery, user-interface, dialog

I'm trying to position my JQuery dialog next to the cursor onmouseover. I NEED to do this using ("html").dialog(). NOT using a selector (since these are dynamically created and is essentially replacing a JS alert on the fly.

I'm getting my x / y coordinates correctly at the time I call .dialog(). But the position attribute seems to ignore them. I also tried setting the position on the container div but it ignores that. What is wrong with my code?

```
var link = "<a onmouseover='getComments()'>Hover for Comments</a>";

$(document).mousemove(function (e) {
    x = e.pageX;
    y = e.pageY;
 });

function getComments()
{
    comm = getCommmentText();
    $("<div>" + comm + "</div>").dialog({
      autoOpen: true,
      show: {
        effect: "clip",
        duration: 500
      },
      hide: {
        effect: "explode",
        duration: 500
      } ,
      position: { 
        my: parseInt(x), 
        at: parseInt(y)
      }
   });
}
```

I Have also tried to force the ui-dialog to a position, but it ignores that

```
$(".ui-dialog").css("left", x + " !important");
```

EDIT: I got it working but it jumps from the left to the right when the dialog finishes loading:

```
$("<div>" + comm + "</div>").dialog().parent().parent().css("left", "100px", "important");
```

How do I stop the default css from overriding mine?

Answer (score 0):

What are the elements with class ui-dialog?

Try:

```
$(".ui-dialog").style('left', x + "px", 'important');
```

Remember:

```
jQuery.style(name, value, priority);
```

Or:

```
$(".ui-dialog").css("left", x + "px" + " !important");
```

x does not contain px unit.

Comment: ty, but this doesn't work. I can set the background colour with the same technique but it seems to ignore position, it just places it in the centre of the screen by default

Comment: yes, well I'm just trying to hard code it first
    $("<div>" + comm + "</div>").dialog().style("left", "-500px", "important");
that only works for background-color

Answer (score 0):

Alright, I figured it out thankfully.

```
$("<div>" + comm + "</div>").dialog();

//dynamically set the position of the Dialog window
$(".ui-dialog").css("left", (x + 25) + "px", "important");
$(".ui-dialog").css("top", y + "px", "important");
```